# Thomas Fantet de Lagny Article on Binary Arithmetic

Tags: reference-request, math-history, binary

In reading Georges Ifrah's The Universal History of Computing, I came across the following passage:

> Quite independently of Leibniz's work, in 1701 the French mathematician Thomas Fantet de Lagny published an article about binary arithmetic, in which he clearly demonstrated the merits of the binary system without (unlike Leibniz) appealing to any religious, philosophical or metaphysical considerations

I have been unable to find the title or a copy of this article. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in [his eloge in the 1734 French Academy of Sciences](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3531x/f119.image)  (Click on the little "i" sign for bibliographic *Informations détaillées*, and page backwards to f115 for the start of the article (on page 107).)  The eloge ends with a partial publication list, but I did not see one for his binary number system.

The last paragraph of [an article about him](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Lagny.html)  mentions he "used binary arithmetic in his text *Trigonométrie française ou reformée* published in Rochefort in 1703."

Comment: they could aslo have tried https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=inauthor%3A%22Thomas+Fantet+de+Lagny%22  I think.